# relative import in test directory

Tags: python, relative-import

My typical Python project structure looks like

```
setup.py
foobar/
    __init__.py
    main.py
    something_else.py
    helpers.py
test/
    addition/
        test_consistency.py
        test_speed.py
    subtraction/
        test_consistency.py
        test_speed.py
```

This works well.

I then notice that the addition and subtraction tests share quite a bit of code, complex assertions and such. I tried to move the code into a helper file

```
test/
    helpers.py
    addition/
        test_consistency.py
        test_speed.py
    subtraction/
        test_consistency.py
        test_speed.py
```

and import from addition/subtraction like

```
from .. import helpers
```

but this fails with

```
E   ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Alright, the test folder is not a "package" and relative imports don't work.
[A well-known Python issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)

How can I share code between the addition and subtraction subfolders? A flat directory structure is not an option. (In real life, the folder structure is more complex than the above example.)

Weirdly, I noticed that pyscaffold *does* to relative imports in `tests/`, see [here](https://github.com/pyscaffold/pyscaffold/blob/master/tests/conftest.py#L22). How do they do that?

Comment: well, just make your test folder a package by empty `__init__.py`

Comment: @Nico Schlömer: `pyscaffold` has empty `__init__.py` everywhere (all subdirectories), you should do the same.

Comment: That's it! I'll be happy to accept if anyone promotes this to an answer.

Comment: How are you running the tests?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D pytest